# Google map with zoom 21 will be shown as a grey area unless i click on it

Tags: java, html, google-maps, maps, google-maps-markers

I have a .net web site, which contain 2 google maps on 2 separate pages as follow:-

**Page 1**

```
<div class="map">                    
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=***&q=3****2&zoom=21&maptype=satellite"></iframe></div>
```

**Page 2**

```
<div class="map">
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=***&q=3****0&zoom=18&maptype=satellite"></iframe>
```

now the map on page 1 will be shown as grey area as follow:-

[image]

and I have to click on the area for the map to be shown. while on the second page the map will be shown correctly once the page load.

now the only differences between the 2 maps are:-

1. each map has its own coordination.
2. the first map has `zoom=21` while the second map has `zoom=18`.

I have noted this problem recently, and i am sure it  use to work well for the past 2 years.
so can anyone advice on the possible sources for this problem? i test this on FireFox, IE11 & google chrome.. and they all have the same problem.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like an update to the Embed API broke that functionality.

Comment: What is the [maximum zoom level](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maxzoom) for the location returning the blank tiles? It's possible that you are specifying a zoom level (21) that is greater than the satellite quality available there

Comment: Would you mind supplying the `q=***` values to determine if this is in fact intended behavior?